# Unable to invoke qwerty VKB when using <Edit text> in Android tablet

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an Android application and in that, to enter text, I have used  for creating text field. But when I run the application in Android tablet, I am unable to get VKB.
Can you help?

---

Code:

```
inputName = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.input_name_id);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(inputName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

With this code, I am able to get VKB without selecting edit text field, but I want to invoke VKB when I click on edittext field.

Comment: Please post some code so that we know where you are stuck

Comment: Please update the question with extra information rather than adding it in comments.  I've done it for you this time, but please remember for the future. Thanks.

Comment: With the above mentioned code vkb is displayed when activity started. not on clicking the edittext view..please reponsd.

Comment: Updated my manifest file with "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" to solve this problem.. thanks every one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after rebooting tVdbM6Dao=Femulator.